# VBA nested frame error handling

Tags: html, excel, frames, vba

So my problem is that I have to click on an element that is nested within two Frames in a html page. I've tried the following, but keep getting `"run-time error '-2147352319'` when I run the line:

```
Set iframedocy = iframedoc.Frames("catalogo")
```

Here's the complete code:

```
Sub download()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.navigate "page"
Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set doc = IE.Document    
Set iframedoc = doc.Frames("frmMain").Document
Set iframedocy = iframedoc.Frames("catalogo")
iframedocy.getElementsByTagName("img")(0).click
End sub
```

and here's the relevant part of the html code

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci2uC.png)

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that `IE.readyState <> 4` does not pay attention to frame content, i.e. it can return before frames are loaded/ready.  Introduce an artificial delay (set a breakpoint & wait) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. Actually, it does not, I've also ran in break mode, and in the original code, I've put the application wait for 3 seconds, but didnt make a difference, as the first iframedoc works. I believe there probably is a problem with the way I'm referring to the nested frame.